# How to regex a branch name?

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have variable with "origin/blahbranch" that I want to substring into "blahbranch", how to substring it? I tried with

```
dev newbranch = (branch1 =~ /.*)[0]
```

but that left me with 
1. / sign included which I don't want
2. the actual git instruction returns error message when embedding the parameter ${newbranch} :

```
"unexpected char: '''"
```

Comment: Try replacing `/.*` with `[^/]+$`

Comment: that would be perfect, but I get `unexpected token [`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming branch1 is string you can use split function

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(branch1.split("/")));
list.remove(0);
def newbranch = String.join("/", list.toArray(new String[0]))
println newbranch
```

Very simple solution considering remote always remains `origin` you can do below

```
def newbranch = "origin/blahbrachwithslash/blahbranch".replace("origin/","")
println newbranch
```

Comment: that could work, but if there are additional `/` signs that needs to be accepted like `origin/blahbrachwithslash/blahbranch` ?

Comment: what is expected output in this case?

Comment: accepted everything after origin/   because I think that later in code to perform a checkout git branch: ${newbranch} is not accepted, I get no revision to build

Comment: ok, although why the arraylist? I'm using git parameter plugin which produces a list of branches, then I choose only one branch and I want to pass it for checkout

Comment: arrayList is to store sub-string generated from splitting of your branch name. This can also be done with `replace` and regex but then you need to consider lot of valid characters for branch name and stuff so this is simplest way I think of

Comment: ok, btw how about cutting "origin/" string out of the original name?